# Can't reference a js file in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am a totally beginner in JavaScript. I want to reference a js.function in HTML. Following is my code. When I run it, I get the error:

> jisuan is undefined

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
<meta name="Author" content="">
<meta name="Keywords" content="">
<meta name="Description" content="">
<title>Document</title>
<script language = "javascript"，src ="myfuns.js"></script>
<script language = "javascript",type="text/javascript">
    var num1 = window.prompt("please input the first num");
    var num2 = window.prompt("please input the second num");
    var operator = window.prompt("please input an operator");
    num1= parseFloat(num1);
    num2= parseFloat(num2);
    document.writeln("the result is" + jisuan(num1,num2,operator));
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>


function jisuan(num1,num2,operator)
{
    var res = 0;
    if(operator =='+')
    {
        res = num1 + num2;
    }else if(operator =='-')
    {
        res = num1 - num2;
    }else if(operator =='*')
    {
        res = num1*num2;
    }else if(operator =='/')
    {
        res = num1/num2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Move the function declaration to the `script` tag in the head, or enclose the current declaration with a `script` tag.

Comment: Assuming that `jisuan` is defined in `myfuns.js`, I would check 1. which folder is the `html` file in (is it in the same folder as `myfuns.js`? 2. I would `console.log()` something in `myfuns.js` to determine if this file is actually getting loaded and read.

Comment: I agree with gave hit f12 and view the console to see if the js file is actually loading, look for 404 errors

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this

```
<script language = "javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

so without the "," 
not this:

```
<script language = "javascript",type="text/javascript">
```

So this

```
 <script language = "javascript"，src ="myfuns.js"></script>
```

would also be this:

```
 <script language = "javascript" src ="myfuns.js"></script>
```

Set all your javascript code between:

```
<script language ="javascript">
```

and

```
</script>
```

so this

```
function jisuan(num1,num2,operator)
{
    var res = 0;
    if(operator =='+')
    {
        res = num1 + num2;
    }else if(operator =='-')
    {
        res = num1 - num2;
    }else if(operator =='*')
    {
        res = num1*num2;
    }else if(operator =='/')
    {
        res = num1/num2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

would be this

```
<script language ="javascript">
function jisuan(num1,num2,operator)
{
    var res = 0;
    if(operator =='+')
    {
        res = num1 + num2;
    }else if(operator =='-')
    {
        res = num1 - num2;
    }else if(operator =='*')
    {
        res = num1*num2;
    }else if(operator =='/')
    {
        res = num1/num2;
    }
    return res;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have numerous errors that would be picked up if you [used a markup validator](http://validator.w3.org).

The particular one causing your problem is here:

```
<script language = "javascript"，src ="myfuns.js"></script>
                               ^
```

You need to have one or more whitespace characters (such as a space) between attributes, but you have a U+FF0C : FULLWIDTH COMMA (`，`). This causes the `src` attribute to not be recognised.

In HTML 5 the `language` attribute is obsolete anyway, so it should be removed. If you want to specify the scripting language you are using (which you should only do if you are not using JavaScript as it is the default) then (since 1996) you should use the `type` attribute.

```
<script src="myfuns.js"></script>
```

Use [a markup validator](http://validator.w3.org) to find the rest of your errors.

Comment: But even with the comma, if the function is moved inside the `script` block then it works.

Comment: @gabe — But the question is asking about how to reference an external JS file.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the space on  `="javascript",src` and  `"javascript",type`

```
<script language = "=javascript",src ="myfuns.js"></script>
//-----------there is no space-^    

<script language = "javascript",type="text/javascript">
//-----------there is no space-^
```

but should be

As  **Quentin** pointed out, the comma should not be used as well.

**Update**

```
<script language = "javascript" src ="myfuns.js"></script>
<script language = "javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: There should not be any commas in there at all… or language attributes for that matter.

Comment: Updated, thank for this pointing out.